# django Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 49903)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I got this error when I passed an `id` in the URL.
Please check my below codes.

**Reference URL as a link in template**:

```html
<a href="{% url 'he_admin:viewcategory' pk=category.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-info" title="View" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i></a>
```

**Urls module**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from he_admin import views
    
app_name='he_admin'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('addproductscategory',views.add_products_category,name='addcategory'),
    path('showcategories',views.ShowCategory,name='showcategories'),
    path('view/<int:pk>',views.ViewCategory,name='viewcategory'),
]
```

**View function**:

```py
def ViewCategory(request, pk):
    try:
        category=ProductCategory.objects.get(id=pk)
    except:
        raise Http404('category does not exist')
    return render(request,"viewcategory.html",{"category":category})
```

**Error**:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code where you're actually using this URL.

Comment: solved                                                                                                                                       some static tag was missing in html  <head >section                                                                                           <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/adminlte.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css' %}">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css' %}">

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it would raise the same error, but there is an issue with the definition of this URL:

```py
path('view/int:pk',views.ViewCategory,name='viewcategory'
```

The PK part is not specified well. Try this:

```py
path('view/<int:pk>',views.ViewCategory,name='viewcategory'
```

Comment: when i use this path => path('view/<int:pk>',views.ViewCategory,name='viewcategory'), it's shows me above error and when i use this path it's run successfully  => path('<int:pk>',views.ViewCategory,name='viewcategory'),